# Glassfish server gets exception from my code

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

When I try to run this code on a browser it displays nothing when I add `session.setAttribute("smodel",udm)`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/LoginServlet"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {



String loginId,password,uname;
UserDetailsModel udm=new UserDetailsModel();
HttpSession session;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;
            try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
       loginId=request.getParameter("loginid");
       password=request.getParameter("password");
       boolean value=readFile();
       if(value){

           request.setAttribute("model", udm);
           session.setAttribute("smodel", udm);
           System.out.println("session running");
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WelcomePage.jsp");
           rd.forward(request, response);

       }
       else{

           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("ErrorPage.jsp");
           rd.forward(request, response);

       }
            }
       finally{
               out.close();
               }
}

boolean readFile(){

boolean value=false;
try{

FileReader fr=new FileReader("ExoticaTravelLogin.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

String data;
while((data=br.readLine())!=null){
String text[]=data.split("~");
if(text[3].equals(loginId)&&text[4].equals(password))
{
uname=text[0];
udm.setname1(uname);
value=true;
break;
}
else{

value=false;
}
}
fr.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
System.out.println(ioe);
}

return value;



}


       }
```

Seems that I get a null pointer exception on the glassfish server:

> Warning: StandardWrapperValve[LoginServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   LoginServlet threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:42) at
>   LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:113)

Comment: What is your question? This is just a bunch of code, makes it really hard for anyone to help you and answer your question. Please edit, add question text to your question body and format code more properly!

Comment: seems null pointer exception on the glassfish server:Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[LoginServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:42)
 at LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:113)

Comment: adding stack trace would be helpful.